Google Maps has stopped giving me spoken instructions when I ride public transport, how do I turn it back on?
Google maps always used to speak audible instructions like "stay on the 16 for 4 stops" and "get off at Dam Square".
It's suddenly stopped doing that as of late. The text notifications still appear, but no spoken instructions.
Such instructions are still spoken while driving, walking or cycling, it's just for public transit that they're gone.
How to I get them back?
I use Google Maps 11.140.0104 (#1067638495) on Android 14 (Google Pixel)

Is your phone volume turned all the way down?  Is your phone in Bluetooth mode, connected to headphones you don't have on?  Does every app besides Google Maps make sound?

I want to say install Citymapper but that's obviously not what you are asking about ;)

@Kyralessa No. No. Yes. Also, audible instructions are spoken in Google Maps in all other modes of navigation, like driving and walking.

@Relaxed Oh, I'll test that app! Thanks

Does it work with headphones?  Does it work with an external Bluetooth speaker (if you have one)?

@Kyralessa It doesn't work with headphones. I don't have a Bluetooth speaker.

That's too bad, I was hoping maybe it was a feature they put in so as not to annoy one's fellow public transit riders, that it only works with headphones.

@Kyralessa That's answered in OP

Related: Google Maps Navigation gives no audio clues for Public Transportation mode

Here are some troubleshooting steps:

Check Settings > Navigation Settings.  There are several settings to look at, such as:

Sound & voice
Mute state
Guidance volume
Play... [several options]
Play test sound


Restart the phone.
Clear the Google Maps application cache.
Clear the Google Maps storage (but this might mean having to re-download offline maps).
Completely uninstall the app, then reinstall it.

There are also Accessibility settings that could have an effect, but as you say the sound works in other apps, it's probably not worth looking at these.
